# How to set a CString in a class from the main file

Tags: c++

I have the following code, which sets the name of a file from `main.cpp` to class `CWav` in `wav.cpp`.

wav.cpp

```
CString CWav::SetWavFileNames(CString Wav) {
    WaveFileName = Wav;
    return Wav;
}
```

wav.h

```
CString SetWavFileNames(CString Wav);
CString WaveFileName ;
```

main.cpp

```
m_pWavPlayer = new CWav(TRUE);
m_pWavPlayer->SetFileName(strFile);
```

The problem is that `WaveFileName` never gets set and I get the following error. Is there anything I'm doing wrong in this code?

> Exception thrown at 0x004056C8 in Authenticate.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x8B006AD0.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x004056C8 in Authenticate.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x8B006AD0.

**EDIT** :

```
CWav::CWav(BOOL StartThread) {
    m_dDecodeGain = 1;
    NumChannels = 1;
    BitsPerOpSample = 8;
    Bits_per_sample = 8;
    SampelsPerSec = 8000;
    RecordingLength = 0;
    m_ulTimeBuffered = 0;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&PlayBackThreadData.WavPlaybackCriticalSection);
    FileOpen = FALSE;
    if (StartThread) {
        PlayBackThreadData.LoadNewFile = FALSE;
        PlayBackThreadData.Exit = FALSE;
        PlayBackThreadData.Play = FALSE;
        PlayBackThreadData.Verify = FALSE;
        PlayBackThreadData.Stop = FALSE;
        PlayBackThreadData.Pause = FALSE;
        PlayBackThreadData.Seek.Seek_Active = FALSE;
        PlayBackThreadData.UnPause = FALSE;
        PlayBackThreadData.Flush = FALSE;
        PlayBackThreadData.ValidateHeaderData = FALSE;
        PlayBackThreadData.SetPageState = NULL;
        PlayBackThreadData.Parent = this;
        m_pPlayThread = AfxBeginThread(CWav::PlayBackProcess, (LPVOID)&PlayBackThreadData);
    }
    else
    {
        m_pPlayThread = NULL;

        // add this to ensure open/close never hangs the program on a non-play CWAV...
        PlayBackThreadData.LoadNewFile = FALSE;
    }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

[image]

Comment: Why does that function return its input?

Comment: @drescherjm its a start to the thread

Comment: I think you need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @drescherjm I don't think that's all of my code so lets agree to disagree

Comment: My point is with so little code we are highly unlikely to be able to help. All we can do is provide guesses.

Comment: Is the this pointer valid for the `CWav`  object? Perhaps the `CWav` no longer exists.

Comment: @drescherjm yes I checked and the pointer is never null after initializing

Comment: It does not have to be null to be invalid. In your picture you have a watch that shows that `WaveFileName` is invalid. Look at the call stack and see if the this pointer is valid for CWav object after the exception. Your code could have freed the pointer and still attempt to use the memory afterwards.

Comment: @drescherjm how could I check that using watch? I also used the same pointer to call everything in the CWav class is that okay

Comment: When you get the access violation break into the debugger and use the "Stack Frame" on the debug toolbar to set that to your code. Then look at the Locals or Autos to see if the CWav pointer is valid.